# Export from python 3.5 to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, export

I scraped six different values with Python 3.5 using beautifulSoup. Now I have the following six variables with values:

1. project_titles
2. project_href
3. project_desc
4. project_per
5. project_mon
6. project_loc

The data for e.g. "project_titles" looks loke this: 
['Formula Pi - Self-driving robot racing with the Raspberry Pi', 'The Superbook: Turn your smartphone into a laptop for $99'] --> seperated by a comma.

Now I want to export this data to a csv.

The Headlines should be in A1 (project_titles), B1 (project_href) and so on.
And in A2 I need the first value of "project_titles". In B2 the first value of "project_href".

I think I need a loop for this, but I didn't get it. Please help me...

Comment: From your description it sounds pretty much straightforward. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few hints:

When you have a string like you want to separate on a given character, use `string.split` to get list, which you can get the first value using `lst[0]`.

Then, take a look at the csv module to do your export.

Comment: Thank you... I tried to split the values. But I get this error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". I put the values in a new variable and split this variable. But it doesn't work.

Comment: It's because you have to call split on a string, not on a list.